# Most efficient way of retrieving data from large number of tables (20-30)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, jdbc

I need to retrieve data from around 28 tables in my java application which I am then going to dump to Elastic Search. I need to use JDBC to query and fetch the data from the database (PostgreSQL in my case.) Are joins the most optimal way to fetch all the data?

From a SQL perspective and also from a PostgreSQL perspective (some feature of PostgreSQL I am not aware about) what is the most efficient way to retrieve data?

To add, one table is the primary table. The other tables are 'join' tables having only two columns containing the primary key from the the primary table and another column which acts as foreign key to another table containing more data which I am not concerned about.

Comment: Usually, the most efficient way to retrieve data is to write a `SELECT` statement that fetches the data you want.  If that contains `JOIN`s then so be it.

Comment: so, performing a join on all the 28 tables would be ideal?

Comment: That depends largely on the form in which you need these data. Dumping tables one by one is the best if you need the raw table data.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - so join the primary table with each of the 28 tables one by one and then do the dumping..won't repeated database hits be expensive?

Comment: No. Joining 28 tables will be way more expensive than running 28 individual selects.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - you mean 28 individual joins correct...?

Comment: Why Joins? `SELECT * FROM table1`, then `SELECT * FROM table2`, and so on. That is the best way to get the raw data. If you need the data in some different format, you may need to join or do something more complicated.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - actually I have a primary table which contains the primary data and the other tables are dependent on it. I need to fetch some data from the primary table and some from the secondary table. (actual scenario: I need to check if a record from the primary table has corresponding records in the other 28 tables).

Comment: I thought you want to *export* the data, not *check* them. I guess you should add more details to your question about what you really want to do.

Comment: Sorry but I do need to export data. I process the data received and then do entries in Elastic search. If the record is present in a particular table I add a Enum to a EnumSet for the record and then format the data to dump it to ES. Not sure if this qualifies as an export.

Comment: I realize now my case might not be of a data export as I am just doing a check in the other tables. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining that many tables in PostgreSQL will take a very long time, not just in the execution phase, but also the planning phase.  The query planner will need to consider many different candidate plans while pulling statistics from all the relevant tables.  There's also the `from_collapse_limit` and `join_collapse_limit` -- [these limits (documentation)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html) cause the query planner to do its own re-arranging of the query and isn't always ideal.

You are likely to be better off pulling the data out and use your programming expertise to digest the data before sending it off to ElasticSearch.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to use hibernate in the application to manage the large number of tables. The object graph will be large but not that complicated.